# SpriteKit - Game lags between didFinishUpdate and next update (during scene rendering)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

**Update**
I removed most of the processes running in my app but still observed these "lags". So I tried a new project (the SpriteKit Demo project shipped with XCode 8 and recorded the frame time. And even here, frames are lagging. Please see the following picture: [Frame time from SpriteKit demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVqWK.jpg). At least this is not effect tight to my game, which doesn't make it easier to debug.. :-/

Can you observe the same effect? You can simply record the times with the following code:

```
var cycleStart = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
var cycleEnd = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
var lastTime = TimeInterval()
var delta = TimeInterval()

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    delta = currentTime - lastTime
    lastTime = currentTime
    print("\(delta) \(cycleEnd-cycleStart)")
    cycleStart = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
}

override func didFinishUpdate() {
    cycleEnd = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
}
```

And I'm still wondering why the lagging frame durations jump to 33ms. Is that the way SpriteKit works, I mean will the next frame be skipped if not all process are finished in time instead of extending a single frame duration by the amount of time required to finish all processes?

**Original question**
my SpriteKit game lags occasionally. Unfortunately I could not identify any function or process so far which might cause the lagging. So I tried to narrow it down by measuring the times elapsing during the whole scene processing. Please have a look at the graph: 
[Plot: Total frame time vs. update->didFinishUpdate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMwX6.jpg)

I plotted the time elapsed between entering the update() function until didFinishUpdate() is called (orange) and the time between one update() and the next update() function, so the whole frame time (blue).

I can't see a direkt link between the lags and a super long time between update/didFinishUpdate. It looks like, as if the rendering process takes longer for some frames.

Another interesting observation: The normal frame rate is 60 (16.6ms), but the "lagging" frames have a duration of pretty much 33ms, so 30fps.

Now my two questions: 
1. Is there any method to analyze what's going on during the rendering process? 
2. Did anyone of you observe a similar phenomenon where apparently a whole frame is skipped (if that's a correct interpretation for the 33ms frames)?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

PS: The times were recorded on an iPhone 7 running iOS 10.2, the app is programmed in swift3.

Comment: Please add some code that demonstrates the problem or we can't do much to help

Comment: I wish I could add some code. Since all the functions are entirely executed between update() and didFinishUpdate(), and there's no relation visible between the lagging frames and a long function execution time, I don't know what code portions I should post.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this kind of issue before but in all cases the fault was mine.

The most common reasons were :

- Rendering animations on SKShapeNodes (I merely had 18 with 7 segment paths each that were rotating).
- Changing a very large background image (in an SKSprite node)
- Heavy processing in the completion block of an SKSprite action.
- Having a very large number (50000+) of object instances going out of scope (i.e. being released) in another thread.
- Other heavy workload in background threads.

Not all of those caused rendering delays but they did cause some noticeable slowdowns in SKScene rendering.

Comment: Thanks, Alain! I have a lot going on in different background threads. I though that's the best way to take away operations from the regular scene update. I'll look into that. But your comment about the large images sounds more promising. I habe an infinite scrolling background out of two sprite nodes. They both have alternating images of approx 320x1000 pixels. Quite large, right? I hope that's the issue. I'll post results once I've investigated that. Thank you